# Dockerfile for Ruby app - why is WORKDIR specified as /usr/src/app

Tags: ruby, docker

Looking at the [official Ruby image Docker page](https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby/) - the sample shows setting the `WORKDIR /usr/src/app`.

Does anyone know why this specific path?

Namely is it ok to just have my app at root or in other words leave out WORKDIR? I know its recommend as per the documentation but I have some issues in it not creating a directory.

Just want to ensure there are no issues in dropping it. I tested my image otherwise and it works as expected.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Linux Documentation project says this about [/usr/src](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/usr.html)

> /usr is shareable, read-only data.
>
> Large software packages must not use a direct subdirectory under the /usr
>   hierarchy
>
> The 'linux' sub-directory holds the Linux kernel sources, header-files and documentation.

I'm not sure why they used that directory, and it's probably not harmful, but it also isn't necessarily the best place for a Ruby/Rails app. At the same time the location you place it doesn't *entirely* matter, but you do probably want to observe some rules:

- Avoid using your `~` (home) folder. This can cause problems if you have libraries that install by default to home, then you try and mount that directory and it overwrites things. Plus, you may end up with artifacts in there (.bash_profile, .config/, etc) that you don't want
- Avoid actual `/` (root) so you don't risk overwriting a system directory

Creating an `/app` directory is the most common pattern I've seen. You'll see in some CI/CD tools that they put your data into an `/app` folder, so that's what I try to use for my Dockerfiles

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing particularly special about `/usr/src/app`.  It's in a standard directory tree, but there's nothing pre-installed there and it's not magic to the interpreter or container in any way.  I wouldn't blink twice if I saw `WORKDIR /app` instead, or another directory.

> is it okay to just have my app at root

That'd be a little weird.  There are some directories that have special meanings, and while IME most Ruby applications don't have subdirectories named `proc` or `sys` or `lost+found`, if they did it would conflict.  A `lib` directory *is* fairly common and you'll have at least unusual overlaps there.

Setting *some* `WORKDIR` is basically universal in application Dockerfiles and there's no particular reason to not use it.  The sample Dockerfile under "How to use this image" from the link in your question would in fact be very typical.